# Adding additional columns of data to CartoDB table? (in-place / no merge)

Tags: data, merge, carto

Is there any quick way to add some data to a table without either a) merging / replacing the whole thing or b) having to do it one cell at a time ?

example: i have a table loaded now with the counties of Arizona.  I would like to add a few columns of county-specific data in-place.  I don't want to merge unless i can merge in-place.

the end result would be as if i exported the data, added columns to it (e.g. in google docs), and created a new table using that same data.  This is the thing to be avoided.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yep, you can do it with SQL. Let's say you have two tables containing rows of data. Both have a column called county_code which is shared. To write a column of data from table_2 into table_1 you would run the following SQL,

```
UPDATE table_1 SET some_new_column = 
  (SELECT 
     some_old_column 
   FROM table_2 
   WHERE 
     county_code = table_1.county_code 
   LIMIT 1)
```

You would have to create the column `new_column` in table_1 and give it the same type (date, string, numeric) as the `some_old_column` in table_2.

You can do this a column at a time to make sure you are doing it okay and then just drop columns from `table_2` when you don't need them anymore

Comment: ahh, wasn't thinking about the tables being accessible to each other but clearly they are in the same db.  i'll give this a shot tonight and come back to mark the question answered.